# how to retrieve data from Firebase Database from different nodes using Firebase Recycler View using onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

There are two nodes

1. Friends->From which I am getting date by using (Friends class)
2. User -> From which I am getting userName , profile Image
   I am using bindViewHolder method. This code does not give me any error but when I run the app and click on friends my app crashed

   public class FriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
        private RecyclerView myFriendsList;



    //Firebase
    private DatabaseReference friendsRef , usersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String onlineUserId;
    private  String userName , profileImage ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);

        //Firebae
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        onlineUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        friendsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(onlineUserId);
        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        myFriendsList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        myFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        myFriendsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        friendList();

    }

    private void friendList()
    {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Friends> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Friends>()
                        .setQuery(friendsRef, Friends.class)
                        .build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends , FriendsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FriendsViewHolder FriendsViewHolder, final int i, @NonNull Friends Friends)
            {
                final String postKey = getRef(i).getKey();
                final  String userIds = getRef(i).getKey();
                FriendsViewHolder.date.setText(Friends.getDate());
                usersRef.child(userIds).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {
                            userName = dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue().toString();
                            profileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profile image").getValue().toString();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                FriendsViewHolder.fullname.setText(userName);
                Picasso.get().load(profileImage).into(FriendsViewHolder.search_profile_image);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_user_display_layout , parent,false);
                FriendsViewHolder viewHolder = new FriendsViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }

        };
        myFriendsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public static  class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        CircleImageView search_profile_image;
        TextView date , fullname;

        public FriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            search_profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_image);
            fullname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_fullname);
            date= itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_status);
        }

    }
   ```

   }

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: date

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Friends` class.